# How to get last location of a device?

Tags: android, location

I am trying to get user's last known location but when i open the app it just shows a blank screen in the textViews where it should show latitude longitude and time. I can't find any flaws or error. So, I need some help. This code worked when I ran it yesterday, but it isn't working now. The following is my

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
final String TAG = "GPS";
private final static int ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT = 101;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 ;

TextView tvLatitude, tvLongitude, tvTime;
LocationManager locationManager;
Location loc;
ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest;
ArrayList<String> permissionsRejected = new ArrayList<>();
boolean isGPS = false;
boolean isNetwork = false;
boolean canGetLocation = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
    tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);
    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetwork = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);

    if (!isGPS && !isNetwork) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection off");
        showSettingsAlert();
        getLastLocation();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection on");
        // check permissions
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0) {
                requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]),
                        ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission requests");
                canGetLocation = false;
            }
        }

        // get location
        getLocation();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
    updateUI(location);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}

private void getLocation() {
    try {
        if (canGetLocation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can get location");
            if (isGPS) {
                // from GPS
                Log.d(TAG, "GPS on");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (loc != null)
                        updateUI(loc);
                }
            } else if (isNetwork) {
                // from Network Provider
                Log.d(TAG, "NETWORK_PROVIDER on");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (loc != null)
                        updateUI(loc);
                }
            } else {
                loc.setLatitude(0);
                loc.setLongitude(0);
                updateUI(loc);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't get location");
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getLastLocation() {
    try {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        Log.d(TAG, provider);
        Log.d(TAG, location == null ? "NO LastLocation" : location.toString());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private ArrayList findUnAskedPermissions(ArrayList<String> wanted) {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

    for (String perm : wanted) {
        if (!hasPermission(perm)) {
            result.add(perm);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
    if (canAskPermission()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return (checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean canAskPermission() {
    return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT:
            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult");
            for (String perms : permissionsToRequest) {
                if (!hasPermission(perms)) {
                    permissionsRejected.add(perms);
                }
            }

            if (permissionsRejected.size() > 0) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissionsRejected.get(0))) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                            requestPermissions(permissionsRejected.toArray(
                                                    new String[permissionsRejected.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No rejected permissions.");
                canGetLocation = true;
                getLocation();
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is not Enabled!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to turn on GPS?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

private void updateUI(Location loc) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUI");
    tvLatitude.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
    tvLongitude.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
    tvTime.setText(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(loc.getTime()));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
}

}
```

Comment: Try - `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: The `getLastLocation()` method just gets the last known location that the device happens to know. Sometimes the device does not "happen to know" its location and `null` is returned. It may also take some time before `onLocationChanged()` gets triggered or it might not happen at all, if the device can't determine its location.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen How do I fix this?

Comment: You'll just need to design your application according to these real-life constraints. You might not always have the latest location available, it might not be up-to-date anymore and getting the device's fresh location may take a while or fail completely. For example GPS typically doesn't work indoors and even it works, getting the location may take several seconds or tens of seconds. (Even more in rarer cases.) And the network location isn't very accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fused Location Provider Client is the best way to do it.
Try with this code for the getLastLocation() method:

```
FusedLocationProviderClient mLocationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
        mLocationProvider.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(activity, location -> {
            if (location != null) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();    
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                //some log here
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below solution and let me know, because it's working fine for me.

Change your provider as

```
String provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
```

You have mentioned this provider in `getLastLocation()` method.

Also add below permissions to your manifest files

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Did you tried this solution? Will you update please?

Comment: Yes, Thanks that was all fine. There was some problem in getting my last location